# Malloc error :incorrect checksum for freed object

Tags: c++, c++11, malloc

I am unable to figure it out. As, why I am getting the error

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x7fd812403a80: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Following is the snippets of the code. If I comment out the function call to method 'pre_compute_nCr', then the code works as expected. However, its only calling function 'pre_compute_nCr', it pops the above mentioned error. In the code, 'binom_obj (i,j)' returns the value of 'i choose k'

```
  void pre_compute_nCr (int n, std::vector<std::vector<uint64_t>>& n_chos_k) {

        n_chos_k[0].push_back(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) n_chos_k[i].resize(i, 0);

        jaz::Binom<int> binom_obj;

        for (uint64_t i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
            for (uint64_t j = 0; j <= i; ++j) {
                n_chos_k[i][j] = binom_obj(i, j);
            }  // for j  
        } // for i
    }


    int dynamicProgramming(int n, XX xx_obj) {

        std::vector<std::vector<uint64_t>> n_chos_k;
        n_chos_k.resize(n);
        pre_compute_nCr(n, n_chos_k);


        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You are overwriting the heap chunk headers, I would guess that your `i` or `j` is writing past the end of a dynamically allocated array. I would definitely fix this as such an error can be readily exploited by hackers.

Comment: `n_chos_k[i][j]` up to `j<=i` is wrong since `n_chos_k[i]` has only size `i`, so index from `0` to  `i-1`.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: Thanks for spotting the error

Comment: Not a worry, @ZephyrPellerin . You can check for malicious activity with [the evil bit](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3514.txt).